# How to avoid copying unexpected indent at the start of each line in Vim?

Tags: python, vim

OS: Mac High Sierra

Vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jul 26 2017 19:10:24)

Vim configurations/settings: installed the awesome version of https://github.com/amix/vimrc

I copied several lines from Vim to clipboard using "Cmd+C" and pasted that to python opened in terminal. It returned "IndentationError: unexpected indent". Below's a screenshot of multi-lines selection in Vim:
[image: screenshot of multi-lines selection in vim]

From the image, we can see one-space ident at the start of each line. But when I move the cursor in vim editor, no space would be highlighted by the cursor.

Question: how to avoid these unexpected indents? Is there any way to set the .vimrc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't told vim to use the mouse.
So what you are doing is just selecting text in the terminal, including everything vim displays for formatting.

To change this, try setting `set mouse=a` in your .vimrc
And take a look at `:h mouse` for more information on what this does.

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem. However, I can't use Cmd+C to copy codes from Vim to clipboard to terminal. Could you help with this?

Comment: Yes, now you are selecting in vim land. You could use normal `y` to yank the text, which is probably the way you should go.  
But you can remap CMD-C to y. `nnoremap <D-c> y`  
But be aware that this might require some more configuration.

In addition, you need to be aware that vim's clipboard is separate from the system's clipboard. The merge the two set `set clipboard+=unnamedplus`